# Using Dsolve with Assumptions/Conditions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, dsolve

I would like to solve the following equation:

```
DSolve[u''[x]+k^2 u[x], u[x],x]
```

if k^2<0 the solution is

```
u[x]-> C[1] e^(kx) + C[2] e^(-kx)
```

if k^2>0 the solution is

```
u[x] -> C[1] Sin [kx] + C[2] Cos[kx]
```

in my equation

k^2=(a-b)/(c-d)

when b >a and c >d, meaning k^2<0

when I plug the equation into Mathematica, it reverses the sign and given me the exponents solution and not the cosine one.

does anyone have an idea how to plug the Assumptions or Conditions into the equation? Or patch between the two so I'll get the true solution?

Cheers

Comment: Your code produces an error: "DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected ..."  It would also be helpful if you posted the expected solution, since you appear to know what it should be.

Comment: This worries me, but can you adapt something like this: sol = u[x] /. 
  DSolve[A u''[x] - ((a-b)/(c-d))u[x] == 0, u[x], x][[1,1]] followed by (sol /. E^(v__*x) -> Cos[v x]+I Sin[v x]) /. (a-b)->(b-a)

Comment: @Bill I've edited and added clarifications

Answer (score 0):

introduce a constant `k2n` which is the negative of your assumed negative `k^2`:

```
 First@DSolve[{u''[x] -  k2n  u[x] == 0  }, u[x], x]
```

> E^(Sqrt[k2n] x) C[1] + E^(-Sqrt[k2n] x) C[2]

now we know  `k2n>0` so back substitute

```
 % /. Sqrt[k2n] -> k
```

> E^(k x) C[1] + E^(-k x) C[2]

As a general answer I don't think there is a way to tell `DSolve`  to make assumptions about parameters.